# More explanation about "XML doesn't support arrays" while there is the <array> tag

Tags: json, xml

Many websites compare XML and JSON and mention that JSON supports arrays while XML doesn't support arrays.

While I can see that we have the  tag in XML for example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<array
name="integer_array_name">
<item>resource</item>
</array>
</resources>
```

so any explanation about what it means by "XML doesn't support arrays"?

Comment: You can have an element named anything that you want, with very few exceptions. The element being named `array` has nothing to do with whether XML supports them or not. You can have an element named `picture`, but that doesn't mean that XML supports displaying graphics.

Comment: Can you point us to a web site that claims XML doesn't support arrays? Perhaps if we see it in context we'll understand what they're trying to say. Certainly XML is able to represent ordered sequences of arbitrary data. (By the way, there are plenty of people on the internet talking absolute nonsense.)

Comment: @KenWhite I understand your point, I mean does XML supports the array in general (a set of values grouped under one thing)

Comment: @MichaelKay 
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-json-and-xml/

Comment: It supports an element containing additional sub-elements, which an external application can choose to parse as array elements, but XML itself does not support the concept of arrays. To use your sample XML above, the <array> element has a child element named <item>, and the <array> element supports multiple child elements, so you can have more than one `<item>`, which could represent the individual items for an array (which is what I suspect the author of the XML you're reading intended). Note, however, that you can do the same thing with an element named <list> or an element named <arrgh>.

Comment: Thanks for the citation. They don't say what they mean, so I can't shed any light. Perhaps they just mean "XML has constructs for representing sequences of values, but thay aren't called 'arrays'".

Answer (score 0):

First of all XML is very flexibel language and it gave us an feature of declaring user define tags.
So it doesn't matter what tag name you gave,XML will declare it.

And in JSON arrays are almost the same as javascript .

Comment: I understand your point, I mean does XML supports the array in general (a set of values grouped under one thing)

Many courses and also websites mention that XML doesn't support arrays while JSON support it (As they compare JSON with XML)

Comment: Yes,  I mean  XML doesn't support array

Comment: The real difference is that JSON supports `orthogonal` arrays: any JSON value can be a member of any array. XML only supports sequences of elements. But it's not really a very interesting distinction because it just means that you meet the requirement in a different way.